# Seeking assistance in understanding and fixing SQL injection vulnerability in my Flask application

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have developed an Flask application for a project, and recently a friend pointed out that it might be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I need help in understanding and addressing this vulnerability.

My application interacts with a sqlite3 database to retrieve and store user data. It utilizes SQL queries to perform database operations. However, I am unsure how SQL injection attacks work and how to prevent them.

Could someone please explain the concept of SQL injection and provide guidance on securing my Flask application against this vulnerability? Additionally, if you can review my code and suggest any necessary changes to prevent SQL injection, I would greatly appreciate it.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import hashlib
import sqlite3
import jwt

app = Flask(__name__)

secret = "$up3r_$3cur4_t0k3n"

def check_username(username):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{username}'")
        res = cur.fetchone()
        if res:
                return True

@app.route('/')
def home():
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/v3/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
        username = request.json.get('uname')
        password = request.json.get('pwd')
        if check_username(username):
                return jsonify({"message":"User already exists"}), 200
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (username, password, isAdmin) VALUES ('{username}', '{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}', 0)")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return jsonify({"message":"User Created Successfully."}), 200

@app.route('/api/v3/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
        username = request.json.get('uname')
        password = request.json.get('pwd')
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{username}' AND password='{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}'")
        res = cur.fetchone()
        if not res:
                return jsonify({"message":"Wrong Username/Password"}), 401
        data = {"username":res[0], "isAdmin":res[2]}
        jwt_data = jwt.encode(payload=data, key=secret)
        return jsonify({"auth":jwt_data.decode()}), 200

@app.route('/api/v3/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate():
        auth = request.json.get('auth')
        data = jwt.decode(auth, key=secret, algorithms=['HS256', ])
        if data["username"] == 'admin' and data['isAdmin'] == True:
                return jsonify({"message":f"Welcome admin! Hope you're okay."})
        else:
                return jsonify({"message":f"Welcome {data['username']}!"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run('0.0.0.0',8090, debug=True)
```

I have tried googling the issue but all went over my head.

Answer (score 2):

So I went through your code & found that there are 3 lines which you need to change for preventing SQL Injection.

Line 13:

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{username}'")
```

Change it to

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?",(username,))
```

Line 30:

```py
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (username, password, isAdmin) VALUES ('{username}', '{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}', 0)")
```

Change it to

```py
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (username, password, isAdmin) VALUES (?, '{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}', 0)",(username,))
```

and

Line 41:

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{username}' AND password='{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}'")
```

Change it to

```py
cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password='{hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()}'",(username,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have this SQL statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{username}'"
```

and {username} is a value a user is passing in (from a form they're filling in, an API they're calling etc.).

If the value passed in was

> 'dsolanki'' AND active_flg = ''Y'' '

Then the SQL statement that would get executed is:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='dsolanki' AND active_flg = 'Y'"
```

i.e. a different SQL statement than the one you wrote in your code.
Obviously this is a trivial example and wouldn't do any damage (even if it executed without error) - apart from possibly not returning a record that does exist. However, if your code/language accepts multiple SQL statements in one string then is would be possible to pass an input like

> 'dsolanki''; DELETE * FROM users; '

which would generate these SQL statements in your code:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='dsolanki'; 
DELETE * FROM users;
```

which obviously would cause damage.

Therefore it is good practice to validate the contents of input strings to ensure that they meet appropriate rules (e.g. a user name cannot contain spaces, must be 8 chars long, etc) - to ensure that an SQL injection attack will fail

Hope this helps?